# Program randomly stopping for no apparent reason

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

I am trying to make an Assembly language program based off of the "3n+1" theory where if the number is odd, times it by 3 and add 1, or if it is even, divide by 2 and keep going until the number 1 is reached. The program asks the user for a positive integer then runs the 3n+1 program and once it reaches 1 it returns to the start (haven't quite figured hat out yet as I keep getting an error saying "relative jump out of range by 0021h bytes" and to have the program stop when the user enters 0. while the program is running, it is to print out each number in the sequence (including the one that the user entered) and keep going until after it prints 1. The problem is that I have checked over my code numerous times and have assembled it successfully in DosBox using the TASM command with no errors or warnings. but when I run it, the program seems to stop and dosbox doesn't give me a prompt for a command like it would when the program exits. This is my code:

```
INCLUDE io.h

Cr        EQU  0DH       ; carriage return
Lf        EQU  0AH       ; line feed

TheStack  SEGMENT STACK
          DW   100H DUP (?)
TheStack  ENDS

Data      SEGMENT
Number    Dw   ?
Prompt1   DB   'Please enter the positive integer of your choice:  ', 0
String    DB   40 DUP (?)
New   DB   6 DUP (?), 0
Int2      DB   '2'

Data      ENDS

Code      SEGMENT
          ASSUME Cs:Code, Ds:Data

Start:    Mov Ax, SEG Data    ; Load Data Segment Number.
          Mov Ds, Ax

Prompt:   Output Prompt1      ; Prompt for first number.
          Inputs String, 40   ; Read the ASCII characters.    
      AToI String      
          Mov Number, Ax ;stops here i think
      atoi int2
      mov Ax, number
      xor cx,cx
loop1:    mov bx, 2
      mov cx, 1
      mov dx, 3
      div int2    
      cmp ah,1
      je isodd
      cmp ah,0
      je nextinst
      xor cx,cx
nextinst: mov ax, number
      div bx
      add ax, cx
      mov number, ax
      cmp ax, number
      Je loop2
      xor cx,cx
isodd:    mov ax, number
      mul dx
      add ax, cx
      mov number, ax      
      xor cx,cx
loop2:    itoa new, Ax
      output new
      mov Ax, number
          cmp Ax,1    ; Compare cx to the limit
          jg loop1   ; Loop while less or equal


Quit:     Mov Al, 0           ; Put return code of zero in Al.
          Mov Ah, 4CH         ; Put DOS function call in Ah.
          int 21H             ; Call DOS

Code      ENDS
          END  Start
```

this is just so frustrating as I have all my loops seemingly set up correctly and have made different changes to the program in desperate attempts to get it to work right, but to no avail! It feels like I'm running around in circles just to fix something that should be easy to fix. What do I need to do in order to get the program to work right? What in my code would cause this to happen? Or is this just an issue with DOSbox?

Comment: Is there a **line number** for the "relative jump..." error? Is it `jg loop1`?

Comment: You should debug this in debugger, as many things will surprise you... (for example `div int2` is not doing what you think it is).

Comment: BTW, does the program at least display prompt and can you enter the number, and does it show some numbers? It's not clear from your description, where exactly it does stop.

Comment: Replace `jg loop1` by next two instructions (in separated lines) : `je quit     jmp loop1`. This is because `jmp` has not distance limit like `jg`.

Comment: @Ped7g Yes, it does display a prompt, and it does allow me to enter the number; however, it does not display numbers.

Comment: Well, that's sort of weird, because by quick look I would expect it to output some garbage at least, but it's hard to follow, as when I see the first bug, my mind basically switch off and I have hard time to "run" it further in head correctly. Anyway, I'm not going to supply your debugger here. If you are really desperate, you can try small portions of [x86 code even online](http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/Asm86/) (emulator is not complete, nor 100% accurate, but for example the code from my answer works fully in it, just do something like `mov ax,12345` ahead of it and switch window->registers)

Comment: But for the third time.. you need to find some debugger. It's next to impossible to program in ASM without debugger, especially for somebody who's learning ASM and doesn't have strong incentive to get it right first time. (I had HW available only for 4 hours per week, so I better had my asm code on paper working, cause 2h were spent just typing it in, then if it did crash on first run, I was out of luck for another week ... that would learn you to think like CPU quite fast ;) ). Now abundance of HW simply allows you to load debugger and watch in luxury, what the code is doing to the CPU state.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I've done that, but the program is now termintating and making dosbox just display a blinking underscore ("_") beside the output I have no idea where in the code it is stopping, so it could be anywhere between where I now have it printing out the user entered number and where I'm having it save the new number in a byte so I can print it out in the next command

Comment: The proper name for this is the "Collatz conjecture", which also yields much better search results than "3n+1 theory".

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, for educational reasons, the main loop can be written like this:

```
    ; ax = n (unsigned greater than 1)
Loop3n1:
    mov     bx,ax       ; copy n to bx
    shr     ax,1        ; divide by 2
    jnc     wasEven     ; CF set when odd from shr
    mov     ax,bx
    add     ax,bx
    add     ax,bx       ; ax = 3*n
    inc     ax          ; +1
wasEven:
    ; here ax = 3*n+1 (odd n), or n/2 (even n)

    ; display ax
    ; make sure ax value is preserved!

    cmp     ax,1
    ja      Loop3n1     ; if (1 < n), loop

    ; jump to start? (and how it will exit?)
```

You should always try to keep close to the theoretical formula, usually anything beyond that is not really needed, often some reorganization of your code will allow you to remove it.

For example here I do divide by 2 and test for evenness with single `shr ax,1` (integer numbers are encoded in computer in bits, which represent powers of two. So shifting a "1" in bit left or right makes it effectively *2 or /2 in value, plus the least significant bit will land into CF, which is used to test if number was even/odd).

If the number was even, I'm done, just display it and loop.

If it was odd, I restore it from a copy - that's the additional non-formula stuff, which is sometimes inevitable, but you would figure it out by trying to do 3*n and missing the n value (as it's already n/2).

Then I do 3n+1 by simple n+n+n+1 to not bother with `mul` and clobbering more registers. In terms of performance those four instructions on old 8086-80486 CPUs will be even faster than `mul` anyway. (Pentium was maybe the first one to challenge it, but then again, since 386 you can use 32b mode and `lea  eax,[ebx*2+ebx+1]` to do the 3n+1 in single instruction.)

And compare the result to 1, to determine if I need to loop again.

And that's it, that's your description of task, and that's what you can achieve by almost 1:1 writing it down into ASM instructions (of course it often takes several tries and pruning/cleaning, reallocating registers and searching for different instruction). Always try to first write the required thing as directly as possible ("task" instructions), then look out for the gaps between - how to bridge them, either by changing the original "task" instruction to fit together with other one, or by some helper instructions when inevitable.

Take some time to try some combinations in head and recalling more possibilities than the first one you see.

Comment: Good news and bad news. good news is it works! Bad news is that it seems to somehow mess up the sequence. when I enter 9, I get the following sequence: 9 28 14 3 10 5 16 8 2 0. which is incorrect. the correct sequence should be 9 28 14 7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1. I'm not sure if I'm forgetting a command somewhere in the code. the body is as follows:

Comment: Prompt:   Output Prompt1     
          Inputs String, 40       
   AToI String      
          Mov Number, Ax 
   mov Ax, number
   cmp ax, 0
   je quit
   Itoa new, ax
   output new 
Loop3n1:  mov bx,ax
       shr ax,1
       jnc wasEven
       mov ax,bx
       add ax,bx
       add ax,bx 
       inc ax
       Itoa new, ax          
       output new
wasEven:  mov     bx,number
       shr ax, 1 
       Itoa new, ax 
      output new 
   Mov number, ax
       cmp     ax,1
       ja      Loop3n1
         jmp     prompt

Comment: @johnerikson: You did change my logic completely. You are missing the point how I tightly use intermediate results from one instruction to other several instructions away. Instead of replacing only that "display ax" with display value, you added it on two places, so for every cycle with odd number you display two values instead of one, and you do some `mov bx,number`, which you didn't update, etc...

Comment: @johnerikson: So you obviously still didn't find any debugger. That's hopeless. Find a debugger, take my source *only* without any change, add `mov ax,9` ahead of it, `halt: jmp halt` at end (infinite loop), and single step instructions + watch CPU state. Until you fully understand what I did. Then start to slowly add things you need (input, output, etc), and after each addition debug it again in debugger single-stepping over each instruction, verifying everything works as expected. (also follow my comments in my code, while debugging, it should be obvious. If not, ASK)

Comment: I found a debugger, but my anti-virus is being a big headache by removing all these dll files that I downloaded, which make the program work. they're not even showing up in the quarantine. Trying to go through this whole process of just getting the debugger to run without my anti-virus interfering is just a large headache.

Comment: @johnerikson: If you are creating DOS executables, you may want DOS debugger, ran inside the dosbox. I tried to search for some common suggestion for dosbox, and I see it's not easy to get working debugging environment there. Looks like using the "DEBUG.EXE" from MS-DOS is one option, other is to steal old DOS turbo debugger somewhere (it's possible to emulate [remote debugging](https://corexor.wordpress.com/2015/12/04/turbo-debugger-remote-debugging-in-dosbox/) ... whoa ... but it will be slow). And dosbox itself can be built with it's own debug facility (more like logging, than stepping)

Comment: @johnerikson in the end I would maybe check [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) ... it has some built-in debugger and generally emulates x86 more thoroughly than dosbox (for the price of emulation performance, which should be not a problem for writing your own asm programs). Unfortunately I never used anything of this (except the real turbo debugger on real 80386 with two monitors (VGA+Hercules) 20+ years ago), so I can't help further. At the moment when I'm posting some short asm at SO, I verify it either at [web](http://carlosrafaelgn.com.br/Asm86/) (very limited), or `edb` in linux.

Comment: "edb in linux" of course means to write 32b or 64b assembler and compile into linux executable.. so it's difficult to debug 16b DOS code like that, as you can't run it as whole, but for writing short pieces of examples it's OK, I just comment out all the `int 21h` stuff and watch register values....